# return a pointer to structure taking no parameters

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I prepare for my C test and found a question where I need to write a declaration in C:

`val` is declared as returning a pointer to struct s and taking no parameters.

I did it like that, but not sure if I am correct:

```
struct s (* val) (void)
```

Comment: I think you have mixed up val and bar. And is it a function pointer you're trying to create?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the mistake

Comment: You've defined `val` to be a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns a `struct s` (not a pointer to `struct s`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a *function pointer* you're aiming for, it should be

```
struct s *(* val) (void)
```

If it is a *function prototype*, it should be

```
struct s *val (void)
```

Answer (score 1):

no `struct s * val(void);`

your version declares a function pointer returning the struct